# Top Level Menu Item points to first item on submenu

Tags: menus

Maybe this is simple, but I can't work it out ... is it possible to have a top-level menu item point to the first submenu item?

For example, if I have a menu structure for a tourist website that goes something like:

- Travel

  - Travel to Destination
  - Travel at Destination
  - Other Travel issues

Can I make it so that if someone clicks the top-level "Travel" menu item, what they see is the Travel to Destination" page?

Using Sparkling theme, if relevant.

Thanks
rd

Comment: Can't you just add the Travel to Destination page to the menu twice, and just change the label for the top-level link?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the menu entry for "travel" with "travel to destination", then change the text in the menu item to "Travel"
You can also do a redirect using a redirection manager plugin and redirect the /travel/ url to the sub category

Comment: Your first suggestion is more or less what I'm doing now, the text of the top-level menu is the same as the text of the first item on submenu. I'm looking for something more like your second suggestion, a redirect, to save me having to keep two parallel pages going every time I edit something. I'll take a look at a redirect plugin. Thanks.